# Websocket server not able to receive messages and transmit realtime

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, websocket, streaming, real-time

Hi i eastablished a ec2 python web socket server.
Here one of the clients using media pipe library will be able to extract pose coordinates from the live web cam and transmit it to the server and the server will be broadcasting the data to the other clients. All should happen in realtime.
But the server is not able to receive it in realtime.
The data has 32 key point coordinates stored as a json key value pair.
The server is able to receive a data bunch and is getting hanged in between for like 5 to 7 sec and then receive the next data bunch.
i want the server to receive ans transmit the data in realtime to the other clients.
Is there an other solution.
Is there any other architecture.
Is there any other solution.
Please help me.

I have no other idea in mind i thought of webrtc but havnt established it